# Domain Access with Google Analytics modules two different google analytics code

Tags: 7, domain-access, google-analytics

I have my main site and i created a subdomain with Domain Access module. for example i have www.example.com and i created www.example.com.uk. I have read that you need to install the Domain Configuration and that would create a block in domain access list that yu can provide your second google analytics code (UA-XXXX-XXX) without any success. Has anyone managed to accomplish that? if not how can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://drupal.org/node/547390#comment-3636764

Comment: I found this one also. I installed and enable the module but is it suppose to add something to the existing Domain Analytics UI ?

Comment: After enabling the module you should be able to set UA codes here: admin/structure/domain/batch/googleanalytics_account

Comment: Additionally you can add this to the module so that the UA code of the google analytics form is also domain-dependent function domain_analytics_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
 if($form_id == 'googleanalytics_admin_settings_form'){
  $form['account']['googleanalytics_account']['#domain_setting'] = TRUE;
  
 }
}